# Why don't the String values get displayed as HTML tags using innerHTML?

Tags: html, angular

I get string data from my database to my variable, I want to display them as HTML tags by [innerHTML], but it doesn't work.
The variable is displayed on string instead HTML Tags.

I tried to use with DomSanitizer but it don't work:

```
    article:Article[];
    (article.articlesTitleHtml:SafeHtml;)
```

in the function:

```
this.article.forEach(elementArticle => {
            elementArticle.articlesTitleHtml = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(elementArticle.articleTitle)
        });
```

in HTML page:

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of articles">
            <div id="{{item.articleId}}">
                <h2 class="chart" [innerHTML]="item.articlesTitleHtml"></h2>
            </div>
```

#### my code:

in Type Script:

```
    articles:Article[];

       ngOnInit() {
            this.apiArticle.getArticleList().subscribe(data=>{
                this.articles=data          
            })
```

in HTML page:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of articles">
        <div id="{{item.articleId}}">
        <h2 class="chart" [innerHTML]="item.articleTitle"></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: your content seems inconsistent, `[innerHTML]="item.articleTitle"` or `[innerHTML]="articleTitleHtml"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, you can [check here...](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zofmaj)

if you can share the type of data that you're dealing with, it will give more insight into the appropriate [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) method which should be called

in my example above, i used both **bypassSecurityTrustHtml** & **bypassSecurityTrustUrl** for the 2 different types of strings which needed sanitization